# validate combox with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

hi i'm new with jquery and i'm trying to validate a combobox in my form, i tried but doesn't work anybody can tell me what i'm doing wrong the combo it's `city` the rest of the others components works well

```
var x;
x=$(document);
x.ready(initEvents);

function initEvents()
{
    var x;
    x = $("#send");
    x.click(pressButton);
}

/*this method  validates the form*/
function pressButton()
{   
    $("#form1").validate(
{   rules:
    {
        'city':'required'
    },
    messages:
    {
        'name': 
        {
            required:'* El nombre es requerido"',  
            minlength:'Debe ingresar al menos dos caracteres'
        },
        'email':
        {
            required: 'Debe ingresar un correo electrónico',
            email: 'Debe ingresar el correo electrónico con el formato correcto. Por ejemplo: ejemplo@ejemplo.com'
        },
        'lastname':
        {
            required:'* El apellido es requerido',
            minlength:'Debe ingresar al menos dos caracteres'
        },
        'phone':
        {
            required:'* Debes proveer un numero de telefono, para ubicarte',
            minlength:'El numero debe tener al menos 7 digitos'
        }
        'city':
        {
            required:'*'
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form)
    {
        /*do something*/
    }
});
```

}

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You should call validate with arguments only once, (move it to `document.ready`).
Then, in your button click you should call `.form()`, finally having this:

```
function pressButton()
{
  $("#form1").validate().form(); //The rest of the code moved to document.ready
}
```

As only 'city' validation is failing, it seems you should also move city validation to 'messages' section, so you'll have this instead:

```
$("#form1").validate({   
    messages:
    {
        'city': 
        {
           required: 'Debe indicar una ciudad'
        },
        'name':
        {
        //...
    }
   //...
});
```

Hope this helps. If not, please send your relevant html.

PS: Saludos, desde La Paz, Bolivia